# Create array from all selected options of particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

very new to this - I'm trying to make an array with all selected options from multiple drop downs. Have tried a little jQuery however only getting an array with the first selected option. When I try the below line in console it only returns selected 'Listening' score (HTML below):

```js
var scoreArr = $.makeArray($('.curScore :selected'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curLang">
 <h3>Enter your four-skills language test scores:</h3>
 <label for="Listening">Listening: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
 <select class="curScore" id="Listening" name="Listening">
    <option value="4">4.0</option>
    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
    <option value="5">5.0</option>
    <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
    <option value="6">6.0</option>
    <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
    <option value="7">7.0</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    <option value="8">8.0</option>
    <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
    <option value="9">9.0</option>
    <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
 </select>
 <label for="Reading">Reading: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
 <select class="curScore" id="Reading" name="Reading">
    <option value="4">4.0</option>
    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
    <option value="5">5.0</option>
    <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
    <option value="6">6.0</option>
    <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
    <option value="7">7.0</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    <option value="8">8.0</option>
    <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
    <option value="9">9.0</option>
    <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
  </select>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you sure? When I run your snippet, I get a two-item array.

Comment: Sorry, the above snippet in fact does return an array, however, returns the value 'option' for each element in the array, for me - I'm wanting to access the actual values selected by the user

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the values and then use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert an array:

```js
var $select = $('select');

var scoreArr = $select.map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  })
  .get();
  
console.log(scoreArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curLang">
  <h3>Enter your four-skills language test scores:</h3>
  <label for="Listening">Listening: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
  <select class="curScore" id="Listening" name="Listening">
    <option value="4">4.0</option>
    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
    <option value="5">5.0</option>
    <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
    <option value="6">6.0</option>
    <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
    <option value="7">7.0</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    <option value="8">8.0</option>
    <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
    <option value="9">9.0</option>
    <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
  </select>
  <label for="Reading">Reading: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
  <select class="curScore" id="Reading" name="Reading">
    <option value="4">4.0</option>
    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
    <option value="5">5.0</option>
    <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
    <option value="6">6.0</option>
    <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
    <option value="7">7.0</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    <option value="8">8.0</option>
    <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
    <option value="9">9.0</option>
    <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: That's great, but could it be amended to specify options contained only within a certain class? (I have other drop-downs elsewhere in HTML doc)

Comment: Just change the selector in `var $select = $('select');` to whatever you need. For example `var $select = $('.whatever select');` - all select elements under class `.whatever`.